# Kivy label texture_size is 0,0 after changing text

Tags: python, kivy

I have a label in my `.kv` file:

```
Label:
    id: question
    font_size: 40
    center_x: root.center_x
    center_y: root.center_y
```

I have the following in my root widget class:

```
class MainScreen(Widget):
    question = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.set_question()

    def set_question(self):
        self.question.text = "placeholder"
        print(self.question.texture_size)

    def on_question(self,instance, value):
        print(value.texture_size)
```

This returns `[0,0]` twice. I was under the impression that `on_question` would fire when the `self.question.text` changed, and that the `value` parameter would be the updated label, and thus with the correct `texture_size`. However, this is not the case and it appears that either `texture_size` is not updated, or that the print statement in `on_question` is called before `texture_size` is set.

How do I access texture_size after it is set?

Comment: It probably isn't guaranteed to update until the next frame. Try using Clock.schedule_once with a delay of 0 (which means next frame), and print the texture_size then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem as the docs recommend to bind on texture_size explicitly, which not worked for me. Furthermore  a manuelly forced refresh with texture_update() did not work as well. So the only way I was able to get the texture size was (as already mentioned in the comments) with a Clock event. Here is my approach, maybe it helps you with your problem.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock


kv_string = """
<MainWidget>:
    question: question_id
    Label:
        id: question_id
        font_size: 40
        center_x: root.center_x
        center_y: root.center_y
"""

Builder.load_string(kv_string)


class MainWidget(Widget):
    question = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.question.bind(texture_size=self.on_question)
        self.set_question()


    def set_question(self):
        self.question.text = "placeholder"
        #print(self.question.texture_size)

    def on_question(self, instance, value):
        if isinstance(value, Label):
            Clock.schedule_once(self.get_texture_size, 0)

    def get_texture_size(self, dt):
            print(self.question.texture_size)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        main = MainWidget()
        return main


MyApp().run()
```